# Populate one dataframe based on group values from another

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have one Dataframe **data**

```
   groupId service local
0        1      s1    l1
1        1      s1    l1
2        1      s2    l2
3        1      s3    l3
4        2      s2    l2
5        2      s3    l3
6        3      s1    l1
7        3      s2    l2
```

and I have a Dataframe **question**

```
   q1  q2  howManyGroups
0  s1  l1              0
1  s1  s2              0
2  s2  l2              0
3  s3  l3              0
4  s3  l1              0
```

I wanna count the occurrences of **question** rows based on how many groups in **data** they appear:

```
   q1  q2  howManyGroups
0  s1  l1              2
1  s1  s2              2
2  s2  l2              3
3  s3  l3              2
4  s3  l1              1
```

I am using this code, but it is really slow:

```
for i,g in data.groupby('groupId'):
  for j,r in question.iterrows():
    if set(r[['q1','q2']].values).issubset(set( g.drop('groupId', axis=1).values.ravel())):
      question.loc[j,'howManyGroups'] += 1
```

Edit: My question dataframe can some times have more/less columns than `q1 and q2`. Sometimes it has only `q1`, sometimes it has `q1, q2, q3`...

Comment: Output doesn't really make sense, There are no combination `s3,l1`  in sample `data`.

Comment: On group 1 we have 

      `s1    l1
      s1    l1
      s2    l2
      s3    l3`

so group one has the values `s3,l1`, even if they are not in the same row @quang-hoang

Comment: @LuizFernandoPuttowSouthier what is the actual size of your dataframes?

Comment: the `data` around 100000 rows and the question is around `10000` rows @Ben. T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first reshaping data to get a row per groupId and unique values in any column service or local.

```
data_ = (data.set_index('groupId').stack()
             .reset_index(name='h')
             [['groupId', 'h']].drop_duplicates()
        )
print (data_.head())
   groupId   h
0        1  s1
1        1  l1
4        1  s2
5        1  l2
6        1  s3
```

then use question and `merge` twice, the first time only on q1 (and h in data_) to get which groupId are associated with the q1, and the second time on q2 and groupId to ensure that both q1 and q2 are in the same group. Finally, `groupby` the original index you kept with reset_index before the merges and use `nunique` on groupId:

```
question['howManyGroups'] = (question[['q1','q2']].reset_index()
                                .merge(data_, left_on=['q1'], right_on=['h'])
                                .merge(data_, left_on=['q2','groupId'], 
                                              right_on=['h','groupId'])
                                .groupby('index')['groupId'].nunique()
                            )
print (question)
   q1  q2  howManyGroups
0  s1  l1              2
1  s1  s2              2
2  s2  l2              3
3  s3  l3              2
4  s3  l1              1
```

If you have a unknown number of qi, you could try something like:

```
df_tmp = (question.reset_index()
                  .merge(data_, left_on=['q1'], right_on=['h'])
         )

l_q = question.filter(regex='q\d*').columns.tolist()
l_q.remove('q1')

for q in l_q:
    df_tmp = df_tmp.merge(data_, left_on=[q,'groupId'], right_on=['h', 'groupId'])

question['howManyGroups'] = df_tmp.groupby('index')['groupId'].nunique()
```

Comment: What if my 'question' dataframe has a variable number of q: `q1, q2 ... qn`

Comment: @LuizFernandoPuttowSouthier you could try to chain the `merge`s, but I doubt of the efficiency, I'll think about it

Comment: Could you please provide the merge chained solution @Ben. T?

Comment: @LuizFernandoPuttowSouthier see the edit, it is the best I can think of with the original method in mind